# How to make middleware checking role user and redirect to different view

Tags: laravel

I am create project in laravel with role user. I use Laravel 5.8, in my project i want the user redirect to the different view using middleware check the user role. 
My table are : 
`users table` : (`name`, `email`),
`roles table` : (`name`, `desc`)
`role_user` : (`id_role`, `id_user`)

I have created middleware **CheckRoleMiddleware** :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    foreach (Auth::user()->roles as $role) {
        if ($role->name == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } elseif ($role->name == 'writer') {
            return redirect('/writer');
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

the routes **web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role'], function (){
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/writer', function (){
    return view('writer.index');
})->name('writer.index');
```

});

the URL change, but unfortunately i can't reach the view by the role of the user login. I hope anyone here could help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Which package are you using for roles? Spatie?

Comment: i'm not use any package. i create my own @TahaPaksu

Comment: If you were using spatie, there would be a middleware like `Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:writer']], function () {`, you can do something like that too.

Comment: Here's the underlying code: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Middlewares/RoleMiddleware.php

Comment: This article explains exactly what you're trying to do in detail. https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/02/12/set-up-role-based-access-control-in-laravel/